# Difference in System.Data.DataTable functions

Tags: c#, datatable, copy

Just trying to figure out what the difference is between these two lines of code. They seem to do the same thing but I'm afraid there is something I'm missing that would perhaps make a difference down the road. Which would be the correct use of setting a data table?

I'll use this data table for my example

```
System.Data.DataTable dtExample = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

And here are the two methods that seem to give me the same thing...

```
dtExample = Function.GetURLTable(); // Function which returns a new System.Data.DataTable object.

// or

dtExample = Function.GetURLTable().Copy();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates an empty table without columns with the default constructor(note the `new`):

```
System.Data.DataTable dtExample = new System.Data.DataTable();
```

This uses your function which returns a fully initialized and filled (?) table:

```
dtExample = Function.GetURLTable();
```

This uses the same function and `DataTable.Copy` to create a clone with the same schema and data:

```
dtExample = Function.GetURLTable().Copy();
```

The last is pointless since it creates a copy of no avail.

The first ist not related since it just uses the default constructor. It is redundant if you use `GetURLTable` to get the table.

So without more details this seems to be most appropriate:

```
System.Data.DataTable dtExample = Function.GetURLTable();
```

Comment: The first part is a global type variable in my application. I have to initialize the data table before giving it data so it's a global scope, but I get what you mean on the . Copy() part.

Comment: @Volearix: your first part does not compile because `System.Data.DataTable()` is a type which you can't assign to the variable. That's why i've added the `new`.

Comment: Ah, sorry I missed that in the question. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, it looks like the first line only calls your function, then assigns it to dt, but the second one because of .Copy, calls the function but then creates an exact copy of the dt you just made and assigns it there. Pretty much, the second way uses twice as much memory/storage as the first; do not use unless you want to make changes to the table and still preserve the initial Datatable.